# How to fully counter a blade attack?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

Can somebody explain to me how exactly to perform the blade counter that also attacks/disarms?

I can avoid being hit by pressing counter (triangle on PS3) and pointing the analog stick away from the enemy when the attack symbol appears and holding it during all 3/4 slashes.

But there is the advanced counter that I only manage to do by sheer luck sometimes. It works somehow by releasing and pressing counter at very specific times (and maybe multiple times). This then hits or disarms the enemy in addition to just dodging the attack.

Could someone please explain this technique in detail with the exact timings and key presses? If known, it would also be interesting if this also works with Shiva's female ninjas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform a blade dodge takedown, you need to release and press Y between each slash. This means that Y needs to be held down as the enemy is swinging their weapon, then quickly released after the swing and pressed before the next.

This does work against ninjas (but not Shiva herself).

Comment: As an addendum to this, I believe you can just hold the left analog stick in the "down" position, regardless of Batman and the enemy's orientation on the screen and the knife dodge and advanced take-down will still work.

Comment: Also, you have to unlock the ability to do a takedown at the end.